# java call action from another action

Tags: java, swing, action

```
countresultsfrom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    Color orginalColor = mcoef.getBackground();
                    switch(countresultsfrom.getSelectedIndex())
                    {
                        case 0: // Mech Cnt;
                            mtotal.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 

                            if(mstatus.getSelectedIndex() == 2)
                            {
                                countresultsfrom.setSelectedIndex(2);
                                // countresultsfrom <----- CALL EVENT ???
                            }

                            etotal.setBackground(orginalColor);
                            ctotal.setBackground(orginalColor);
                        break;
                        case 1: // El Cnt;
                            etotal.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                            if(estatus.getSelectedIndex() == 2)
                            {
                                countresultsfrom.setSelectedIndex(2);
                            }

                            mtotal.setBackground(orginalColor);
                            ctotal.setBackground(orginalColor);
                        break;
                        case 2:
                            ctotal.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                            etotal.setBackground(orginalColor);
                            mtotal.setBackground(orginalColor);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

how to call listener one more time ???

Comment: @MarcoS as U can see i have `if(estatus.getSelectedIndex() == 2)` and if its true I want to set selectedIndex on 2 and change background color of textfield but I want to do this automaticly not handly by writing `etotal.setBackground(orginalColor);` multiple times

Comment: mmm ... I'm still confused. Anyway, it seems that you want to notify again listeners from within your listener method (I'm not sure this is a good thing). For doing that you should (1) build a new instance `e1` of `ActionEvent`, (2) get _somehow_ a reference to an instance `c` of (a subclass of) an AWT `Component`, and (3) call `c.processEvent(e1)`. Again, I'm not sure this is a good thing to do. Maybe you should revise your design.

Comment: It looks like you don't want an `Actionlistener` but rather an `ListSelectionListener` on your `countresultsfrom` instance.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could simply call `yourListener.actionPerformed(/*some event*/ e)`. Note that it will not be handled as an event, but as a regular method call.
2. #1 is the simple technical way. It is not recommended. If you want some logic to occur, wrap it in a method and call that method, ActionListeners are meant for handling GUI events.

Answer (score 2):

your descriptions isn't clear for me, but there is basicall two ways

1/ create own `Class someName implements ActionListener`

2/ create `java.swing.Action` some examples for that on [Action](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/0060__Action.htm)

EDIT:

if your countresultsfrom is JList, then all ours advices (maybe) didn't correct at all http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all extract your action performed method to a separate class in your code. It could be a private static class in the same class you wish to call. e.g

```
private static class ColorActionHandler implements ActionListener {
   //implement your method here by looping twice. or create a method for your logic and then call it in a for loop in the actionPerformed method
}
```

and pass an instance of this class in the addActionListener of your countresultsfrom button.

Answer (score 1):

Do you wish `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` to be invoked twice on every action?

If so, wrap the block starting with `Color orginalColor = mcoef.getBackground()` in a for-loop. `for (int i=0; i<2; i++) { ... }`